# Efficient ways to sleep?

Tags: c++, performance, sleep

I am developing a simple C++ application that does some networking. I need it to send UDP packets to another application over the Internet, but in order to prevent any congestion I need to tune the send rate at a specific speed. Therefore, I need my program to sleep between two consecutive packet being sent.
usleep() function looked like a good choice, but for reasonably fast connections I get to sleep for very short amounts of time, in the order of microseconds. It actually works reasonably well even for these rates, but I noticed that it comes at a huge cost in terms of CPU. As an example, I tried to do just this:

```
while(true) usleep(100);
```

This just loops on a sleep command, each of 100 microseconds, right? Now, the CPU speed is in the order of the GHz, so 100 microseconds means a sleep time 5 orders of magnitude bigger than the clock speed. But just this burns 10% of my CPU usage.

So what? Am I doing something wrong? I worked around this by setting wider intervals and sending packets in small series, but nonetheless I would like to know if there are reasonably efficient alternatives to usleep for sleeping for small amounts of time.

Thank you very much!

Comment: The time it takes the OS to switch to another process and back can be significant at those levels. 5 microseconds for a switch (and 5 us back) doesn't sound out of line.

Comment: ensure you have a good matress, good cushion, good room temperature, not too much light or noise disturbance and you should sleep efficiently.

Comment: Great discussions below. I would only add 1) 10% is some overhead, but actually not bad in the grand scheme - chances are there are bigger issues elsewhere. 2) You might try bursting, as in send 10 packets, then sleep for 10 times as long.

Comment: Efficient ways to be inefficient hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody knows how usleep is implemented, as far as the spec goes. Now in practice you could look into the code to be sure of what it is actually but in my recollection it is a spin check. You cannot expect to sleep for amount of times that are smaller than one kernel tick. Therefore about 10 milliseconds, which is 10000 microseconds. Sleeping the CPU would mean to program an interruption at the desired wake up time which is generally expensive and cannot be done in 100 micro, therefore the spin.

Comment: You assume I haven't read every implementation of 'usleep' ever created :].

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Datagram Congestion Control Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datagram_Congestion_Control_Protocol)? It's proposed for standardization as [RFC4340](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4340) and you may be able to find existing implementation rather than trying to implement your own congestion control.

Also check out http://www.read.cs.ucla.edu/dccp/ for implementation and further links.

Comment: This is not an answer. It's a comment to the original question. An answer would actually address the question asked.

Comment: @KenWhite: IMO, the original question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). OP put X as question title, but I consider answering Y to be a valid response as the original question does include sufficient information to decide for it.

Comment: Your "answer" provides no information other than two links to off-site locations; if those links are unavailable for some reason, there is no meaningful content here. Answers should be self-sufficient; comments should be used for providing suggestions and links to off-site locations.

Comment: @KenWhite: That's why I put in the full name of the protocol and the RFC number. If the links becomes outdated, people will still be able to update it based on the information within the post.

Comment: [meta.se] has [a post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/172661) about why these types of answers are discouraged. Your post is a comment ("You should consider <this>. See here and here for info."), which is not an answer **here**. You've not even provided any information about *why* the poster should consider this protocol. "It's standardized" isn't a reason. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite: I'm well aware of that meta, and I disagree that it applies. An answer describing how DCCP works would just be a copy of RFC4340 and the OP isn't asking how DCCP works but how to implement congestion control. If the OP decided he wants to use DCCP, he hadn't decided whether he wants to implement DCCP (in which he'll need to read RFC4340) or adapt an existing implementation (in which he won't need to read RFC4340). IMO, this is the only reasonable level of details given the current information given by OP.

Comment: OK. I still disagree, but I offered the opportunity. :-) I'm afraid I have to downvote this answer in its current form, as it provides no information about why this protocol should be considered. I didn't ask that you describe the entire protocol, but an explanation of why it should even be a consideration would be appropriate, especially when providing it for someone who appears to be relatively inexperienced (given the poster is considering a rapid sleep loop at all). Sorry.

Comment: @KenWhite: You're of course, free to disagree/downvote. But I think the rationale is a rather mundane and generic one that always applies when considering reinvention vs reusing existing implementation, namely: "Implementing X is difficult and reusing an existing library Y would be a major boost to productivity, but Y adds dependency to something you don't write and is more generic than what strictly needed, which may turn out to be useful as the program grows." Replace X with any difficult problem and Y with any libraries/technologies that solves X.

Comment: I understand the XY problem. :-) My issue is not whether or not your links might be applicable. It's whether or not you've provided information about why it might be so. "It has a standard" isn't sufficient; IMO, it's the equivalent of a poster saying "I have an algorithm in language A that I'm having trouble with. Can you help?" and someone answering "You should try language B instead. It has a standard. Click this link for the documentation for that language.". Reasoning about *why* it would be relevant might make it an answer; a link and "standardized" does not do so, IMO.

Comment: +1 excellent suggestion - clearly addresses the underlying need better than the sleep would.